# Batman.js: Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found

Tags: polymorphic-associations, batman.js

I'm running into an issue trying to implement polymorphic associations on a Batman model. I'm getting this error in the console:

> Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found.

I'm having a hard time tracking down where I am going wrong. Where should I look to find the missing piece?

My models look something like this:

```
class Admin.Product.PopularCollectables extends Batman.Model
  @belongsTo 'collectable', polymorphic: true

class Admin.Item extends Batman.Model
  @hasOne 'popular_collectable', as: 'collectable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Batman loads a related model in an association, it checks a namespace. By default, the namespace is `Batman.currentApp` (which is your app after you call `MyApp.run()`), but you can also pass a namespace when you declare the association:

```
class Admin.Item extends Batman.Model
  @hasOne 'popular_collectable', as: 'collectable', namespace: Admin.Product
```

That way, Batman will look for `PopularCollectable` on Admin.Product instead of on Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this issue by embedding the `belongs_to` side of a `has_many` relation inside the parent Batman Model instance when it is sent to the client from Rails:

```
format.json {render :json => @post, :include => {:comments => {:include => :comments}}}
```