# Batman.js: Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found. Same namespace

Tags: polymorphic-associations, batman.js

I am trying to set up the polymorphic association in Batman as documented [here](http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.model_associations.html#polymorphic_association_options). I am using LocalStorage and keep getting the following message:

```
Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found.
```

My model is a follows:

```
class App1.Model extends Batman.Model
  @persist Batman.LocalStorage

class App1.Superpower extends App1.Model
  @resourceName: 'superpower'
  @encode 'id', 'name'
  @belongsTo 'superpowerable', polymorphic: true

class App1.Hero extends App1.Model
  @resourceName: 'hero'
  @encode 'id', 'name'
  @hasMany 'superpowers', as: 'superpowerable', polymorphic: true

class App1.Villain extends App1.Model
  @resourceName: 'villain'
  @encode 'id', 'name'
  @hasMany 'superpowers', as: 'superpowerable', polymorphic: true
```

and the code I use to instantiate all:

```
superman = new App1.Hero(name: "Superman")
superman.save()
super_strength = new App1.Superpower(name: "Super Strength")
super_strength.save()   # -> gives "Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found."
invincibility = new App1.Superpower(name: "Invincibility")
invincibility.save()    # -> gives "Related model undefined for polymorphic association not found."

superman.get('superpowers').add super_strength
superman.get('superpowers').add invincibility
superman.save()
super_strength.save()
invincibility.save()

console.log superman.toJSON()
console.log super_strength.toJSON()
console.log invincibility.toJSON()
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076502/batman-js-related-model-undefined-for-polymorphic-association-not-found) it depends on the namespace, but they are all the same in my code, so I'm really wondering what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh oh... I wrote that example so if it doesn't work, I'm to blame :)

Just to be sure, did you call `App1.run()` at the beginning of that script? I [ran into that issue while testing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/batmanjs/2pO3hqmILrc) last week -- gotta call `run` to load associations!

**Edit:**

Oh, it looks like a matter of using the API just right. You have to be explicit with the `#{label}_type` and `#{label}_id` of the related models. Batman.js will load the associations from JSON just fine, but you'll have to specify them when initializing a new record, for example:

```
super_strength = new App1.Superpower
  name: "Super Strength"
  superpowerable_id: superman.get('id'),
  superpowerable_type: 'Hero'
```

I put up a JSFiddle where it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/2atLZ/2/

I'll go back to the docs and add a note about this! Long term, would be great if the API just accepted `#{label}` then extracted `#{label}_id` and `#{label}_type`... but for now, it's not so.!

Comment: Yes, I just added it but the result is the same.

Comment: looks like a matter of including the `superpowerable` attributes when initializing a record. Whaddya think?

Comment: That works, thnx a lot! I have to say that (besides that warning) it also works fine with just declaring "superpowerable: superman". Declaring the id and type results in the relation only on the super_strengh, while "superpowerable: superman" also results in the relation at the superman-side.